# put random numbers into a UIPicker column

Tags: objective-c

This is what I want:

How do I randomly select an object from the arrays I have to populate the first three columns of my UIPicker. I want the last two columns to remain unaffected by this action. So when the user clicks "generate" button, they will put random objects into the first three columns of my picker. Here is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

self.column1Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"+10", @"+9", @"+8", @"+7", @"+6", @"+5", @"+4", @"+3", @"+2",     @"+1", @"0", @"-1", @"-2", @"-3", @"-4", @"-5", @"-6", @"-7", @"-8", @"-9", 
                     @"-10", nil];

self.column2Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"+", @"-", nil];

self.column3Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"+10", @"+9", @"+8", @"+7", @"+6", @"+5", @"+4", @"+3", @"+2", @"+1", @"0", @"-1", @"-2", @"-3", @"-4", @"-5", @"-6", @"-7", @"-8", @"-9", 
                     @"-10",nil];
self.column4Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"=", nil];
self.column5Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"+20", @"+19", @"+18", @"+17", @"+16", @"+15", @"+14", @"+13",    @"+12", 
                     @"+11", @"+10", @"+9", @"+8", @"+7", @"+6", @"+5", @"+4", @"+3", @"+2", 
                     @"+1", @"0", @"-1", @"-2", @"-3", @"-4", @"-5", @"-6", @"-7", @"-8", @"-9", 
                     @"-10",@"-11", @"-12", @"-13", @"-14", @"-15", @"-16", @"-17", @"-18", 
                     @"-19", @"-20", nil];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I haven't tested it though. This also assumes your UIPicker is called picker.

```
int column1Random = (arc4random() % [colum1Array count])-1;
[picker selectRow:column1Random inComponent:0 animated:YES];

int column2Random = (arc4random() % [colum2Array count])-1;
[picker selectRow:column2Random inComponent:1 animated:YES];

int column3Random = (arc4random() % [colum3Array count])-1;
[picker selectRow:column3Random inComponent:2 animated:YES];
```

You Need to Update the pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponents and the pickerView:titleForRows:forComponents methods

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent :(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    if (component==0) {
        return [column1Array count];
    } else if (component==1){ 
        return[column2Array count];
    } else if (component==2){ 
        return[column32Array count];
    } else if (component==3){ 
        return[column4Array count];
    } else {
        return[column5Array count];
    }
}
// Method to show the title of row for a component.
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{ 
    switch (component)  
    {
        case 0:
            return [column1Array objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [column2Array objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [column3Array objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 3:
            return [column4Array objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 4:
            return [column5Array objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work. IBAction doesn't seem to happen. When I click on generate button, error occurs and it shuts down. Although there are no errors listed in code before I run it.

Comment: @user908462 can you list the code for the IBAction? Did the IBAction work before put the code I gave you in it?

Comment: -(IBAction) generate
    I don't think I'm doing the IBAction properly. This is all I have and I have connected the generate button in xib file

Comment: Try this
`-(IBAction)generate 
{
int column1Random = (arc4random() % [colum1Array count])-1; 
[picker selectRow:column1Random inComponent:0 animated:YES]; 
 
int column2Random = (arc4random() % [colum2Array count])-1; 
[picker selectRow:column2Random inComponent:1 animated:YES]; 
 
int column3Random = (arc4random() % [colum3Array count])-1; 
[picker selectRow:column3Random inComponent:2 animated:YES];
}`

Comment: OK, it works now, but when I run, only the first column of objects appears. I can make that column generate a spin and land on a random object. But the other four columns are blank/empty.